# What is the best way to resolve dependencies between my classes when I write a library?

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-injection

I'm doing a small homemade project and I noticed that I wish to reuse a portion of code in other projects.

The conclusion is to move this code in a separate module and then publish it in my artifactory (I'm using maven) so it will become reusable.

The problem is that classes within my new module rely on each other. Usually, when I develop non-library project, I use Spring's inversion of control feature to resolve dependencies between the classes. But I can't use the dependency injection in my module, because the dependencies will be resolved only when bean is obtained from container.

Therefore, lets imagine the following situation:

I have Class1 in my module. It has field of type Class2, which should be.. lets say.. an instance of the same object always (i.e. singleton). My own ideas how to resolve it:

1) If Class2 doesn't contain any state, only methods (and plays an utility role) I can make it just static. Therefore I won't need to resolve this dependency, since I don't need to create it's instance anymore. But as a result, it can become really hard to test this type of class.

2) I can implement singleton pattern without using DI. The static Class2.getInstance() method could work, right?

3) I can forget about the idea of using singleton pattern and just create instance of Class2 with "new Class2()" expression (inline with field declaration or in Class1 constructor)

4) Somehow to use dependency injection so it could in a 'magic' way to inject my bean inside another one without using a container.

What is the best approach?

Comment: Just create a jar with pojos in it. In the application that uses the jar you can init the classes using xml or @Configuration class.

Comment: Do I understand correcly, that following your approach, if I want to use the class from jar in another project, I need to write configuration for this class in my application? So in every project, where I use the library, I should cretate xml or annotation config?

Comment: And another one case. What if the jar will be used in application, where DI is not used? Does developer will have to include spring framework in the project dependencies just for library configuration?

Comment: If you use my approach your library will not be dependent on Spring, the lib will be just pojos. You can use it with Spring, other DI framework or create the objects with `new`. Another way will be to annotate your pojos with `@Component`(and it's sub annotations) and in the parent project, just `scan` for these classes, but that way the library will be dependent on Spring, and you have to include the spring jars even if you do not use Spring.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got your point. Two more questions. Creating the objects with new - do you mean that in my application I will create a new instance of Class1 and via setters will set dependency? And do I understand correctly, that if I want the developer to spend as less time on library configuration as possible, the approach of @Component is the best one? Because in case of creating an xml config, programmer have to describe in xml dependencies of class. And dependencies of it's dependencies etc. And what about getInstance() approach? Does it have side effects?

Comment: My aim is to make my library as much pre-configured for usage as possible. So that end user could include it to the project, get an instance of the class and use it. :)

Comment: By "create the objects with new" I meant "Not using DI". Yes using `@Component` will make the lib easier to use. Just put the jar in the classpath and ComponentScan it .

Comment: Yeeeap, thank you. Everything seems clear now.